# Is /etc/init.d/hostname.sh still an option for debian stretch?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, hostname

I changed the host name and went to make it stick, but my previous solution didn't work.  I am using Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/L.  Is there a new way to do this (other than reboot)?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /etc/init.d/hostname.sh
-bash: /etc/init.d/hostname.sh: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: Use `hostnamectl`: `sudo hostnamectl set-hostname NAME`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hostname.sh` has never been the right thing to use.  Not only is it one of the van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts that systemd specifically masks on Debian, but running it *was not* the way to make a hostname persistent across reboots *even with* van Smoorenburg `rc`.  It's the script that *reads* the persistent hostname.

The static hostname, from which the dynamic hostname is initialized during bootstrap, is stored in `/etc/hostname` on Debian Linux.  You can edit that file directly, or use tools such as `hostnamectl` which use Desktop Bus, a client-server API, and a started-on-demand server program to … [write that file for you](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v235/src/hostname/hostnamed.c#L310).  ☺

## Further reading

- Franklin Piat, Christopher Soellinger, Matthias Weiler et al. (2017). *[How To Change Hostname](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/ChangeHostname)*.  Debian wiki.

Comment: Wasn't implying persistent across reboots as editing `/etc/hostname` (and likely `/etc/hosts` for domain name) does as well.  But it will not take affect until the machine is re-boot (or the old `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh` was executed).

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/ChangeHostname also describes using `invoke-rc.d hostname.sh`.