# How can the output of `uname` change in a VM after a physical server was patched?

Tags: kernel, virtual-machine, hosting-services

My Zabbix monitoring system told me that the `uname` output has changed on a virtual server (`Host information was changed on ...`). The ISP has shut down the entire server in order to perform some security patches on the physical hardware. How can it be, that the kernel information, which is received by the `uname` syscall, has changed after that? In my understanding, the patches pertain a completely different system layer and should have left the software OS VM layer untouched, isn't that so?

Comment: You're probably using containers.

Comment: Is the monitoring tool so unhelpful that it does not say _what the change was_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the kernel will change the output of `uname` (or at least, `uname -v` and `uname -a`).

If you’re running a full virtual machine, that should only change when you update the kernel in the virtual machine.

But there are many hosting systems which use an external kernel: this includes containers, but also OpenVZ. It’s likely you’re using that.

Comment: Well, on `AIX` the output of `uname -r` may change since AIX was written after reading AT&T man pages. By doing that, they confused `-r` and `-v`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative possibility, in addition to the kernel having actually changed.

The hostname is one thing that `uname` can output.  If before the restart you updated the *static* hostname (i.e. the one stored in a configuration file) but did not update the *dynamic* hostname (i.e. the one stored in kernel memory), then the restart will have yielded different outputs of `uname -a` before and after.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409449/5132